# Google Looker Studio regex_extract challenge

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to create a new field that takes the Page referrer value and pulls a string from the URL when it is found.

According to the validator on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) this should work for me.

`(?<=searchTerm\$)(.*?)(?=\.)`

It is returning a valid result (blue) with the test string: https://www.sampledomain.org/searchTerm$blue.html

This is what I have used in Looker but it has not yielded a valid output:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page referrer,'(?<=searchTerm\\$)(.*?)(?=\\.)')
```

Comment: Can you add here a few scenarios of input & ideal output you expect to see in looker?!